# Actionscript - After I do removechild(), and re add with addChild() the MC keeps moving

Tags: flash, actionscript, collision

I have a MC that the mouse can drag and slide, when it gets removed from the stage when it hits an out of bounds object. I re add it to the stage at the x,y position it originally started from but when I re add it it continues to slide in the direction it was going before it was removed.

function __checkHit($evt:Event):void {

```
if (this.test_object.hitTestObject(bounds1)) 
{ 
    // do our in-circle check
        stopDrag();
        removeChild(test_object);
 test_object.x = 437.25;
 test_object.y = 808.3;
 addChild(test_object);
 }
else
{
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
var props:Dictionary=new Dictionary();
var currItem:Sprite;
var mass=5;
var friction=0.9;
var drag=false;
...
function onMovement(e:Event):void {
    var instanceX=e.currentTarget.x;
    var instanceY=e.currentTarget.y;
    var instanceR=e.currentTarget.rotation;

    if (props[e.currentTarget].drag==false) {
        instanceX+=props[e.currentTarget].vX;
        instanceY+=props[e.currentTarget].vY;
    } else {
        // Set Current Mouse Position
        var mx=stage.mouseX;
        var my=stage.mouseY;

        //Calculate Distance Traveled
        var dmx=mx-props[e.currentTarget].mx0;
        var dmy=my-props[e.currentTarget].my0;

        // Set Previous Mouse Position
        props[e.currentTarget].mx0=mx;
        props[e.currentTarget].my0=my;

        // Calculate Force
        var fx = (dmx - props[e.currentTarget].vX) * mass;
        var fy = (dmy - props[e.currentTarget].vY) * mass;

        // Calculate Offset Between Mouse and Registration Point
        var ax=mx-instanceX;
        var ay=my-instanceY;

        // Calculate Rotation from Offset
        var t=fx*ay-fy*ax;

        //Set Velocity = To Distance
        props[e.currentTarget].vX=dmx;
        props[e.currentTarget].vY=dmy;

        // Set Rotation Angle
        props[e.currentTarget].vR+=t*.005;

        // Set Instance = Instance + Velocity
        instanceX+=props[e.currentTarget].vX;
        instanceY+=props[e.currentTarget].vY;

        // 
        var dx=mx-instanceX;
        var dy=my-instanceY;

        // Convert Degrees to Radians
        var cos=Math.cos(props[e.currentTarget].vR*Math.PI/180);
        var sin=Math.sin(props[e.currentTarget].vR*Math.PI/180);

        // Calculate Offset Points After Rotation
        var aax = dx - (cos * dx + sin * dy);
        var aay = dy - (cos * dy - sin * dx);

        // Set Instance Points after Rotation
        instanceX+=aax;
        instanceY+=aay;
    }

    instanceR-=props[e.currentTarget].vR;

    // Bounce Off Edges
    if (instanceX<0) {
        props[e.currentTarget].vX*=-1;
        instanceX=0;
    }
    if (instanceX>stage.stageWidth) {
        props[e.currentTarget].vX*=-1;
        instanceX=stage.stageWidth;
    }
    if (instanceY<0) {
        props[e.currentTarget].vY*=-1;
        instanceY=0;
    }
    if (instanceY>stage.stageHeight) {
        props[e.currentTarget].vY*=-1;
        instanceY=stage.stageHeight;
    }

    e.currentTarget.x=instanceX;
    e.currentTarget.y=instanceY;
    e.currentTarget.rotation=instanceR;

    props[e.currentTarget].vX*=friction;
    props[e.currentTarget].vY*=friction;
    props[e.currentTarget].vR*=friction;
}
```

Comment: Where is the direction/velocity defined?

Comment: Made the edit. As you can see they aren't defined publicly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell in your code, it looks like the velocity isn't reset to 0 when the object is re-added to the stage.  Removing from the stage doesn't change any properties, so when it's removed and re-added it still has the same velocity values.

Comment: Are there variables I should declare publicly so I can reset their value? Which ones?

Comment: It looks like vX and vY store velocity, so I would start with those.  You don't have to make them public however -- in fact, I would recommend you instead create a public function that you call when removing the object that does all the needed de-initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you only have to reinitialize your variables (velocity, direction...) when you call `stopDrag`.